# How to get count of all items in a criteria GORM query

Tags: grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

So i have this criteria query that is getting 10 feature articles that have itemchannel objects that are of type 4 and in a channel of id 1 i.e get me top 10  articles  which are of type feature and in channel x.

```
def criteria = Feature.createCriteria()
list = criteria.list {
    maxResults(params.max)
    itemChannels {
        eq ('itemType.id',(long)4)
        eq ('channel.id',(long)1)
    }
}
```

How do i get the total count efficiently i.e. i have the articles for page 1 but i need the total number for pagination?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think i sorted this.

```
criteria = Feature.createCriteria()
count = criteria.get{
    projections {
        countDistinct('id')
    }
    itemChannels {
        eq ('itemType.id',(long)4)
        eq ('channel.id',(long)2)
    }
}
```